# How to remove duplicate results from the result of a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two Tables - Departments having Dept_Id, Dept_Name and Dept_Address where Dept_Id is the primary key and another Employees table having Emp_Id, Emp_Name, Emp_Skill and Emp_Dept_Id where Emp_Id is the primary key and Emp_Dept_Id as the foreign key referencing Dept_Id of Departments table.

Now, the task is to find the Department wise Skill. Moreover, the order of the results are descending order of Department Names and ascending order of Skills with no duplicates.

I am stuck at the two way ordering of the results and the removal of the duplicates.

'DISTINCT' was not working for me.
I used a query -

```
SELECT d.Dept_Name
    ,e.Emp_Skill
FROM Departments d
    ,Employees e
WHERE d.Dept_ID = e.Emp_Dept_Id
ORDER BY d.Dept_Name DESC;
```

My output was as follows -

```
Training DBA
Training Analyst
Sales Programmer
Finance Analyst
Finance Programmer
Finance Programmer
Finance DBA
Finance DBA
Development Programmer
Development Programmer
```

whereas it should be -

```
Training Analyst
Training DBA
Sales Programmer
Finance Analyst
Finance DBA
Finance Programmer
Development Programmer
```

The input tables were not provided. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: If you are using SQL query use **DISTINCT**. 

Checkout this link for more detail : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: And how to bring about the two-way Ordering of the results?

Answer (score -1):

Simple use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  d.Dept_Name,e.Emp_Skill FROM...
```